# c++ event handling away from vc++

Tags: c++, event-handling

i want to know how to create events like mouse events or onkeypress (hotkey) event etc in c++ but not the in Microsoft visual c++ environment....

if you can suggest any ebook or any tutorial to learn from.....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are no such thing as "events" in C++.

Those only exist in a specific programming framework. Since you mention "Visual C++", I assume that you're thinking of Windows Forms, which is an object-oriented wrapper for the Win32 API that allows you write applications targeting the .NET Framework. The .NET Framework supports events, delegates, and other handy features, but those have nothing to do with the C++ language.

You will need to use whatever environment is required to support the framework you're programming to. For .NET WinForms applications, that is generally Microsoft's Visual C++. However, you can use whatever text editor you want. This has nothing to do with the IDE and everything to do with the compiler and the target framework.

Answer (score 0):

Learn Qt, wxWidgets, gtkmm -- they all have events in some form.
Qt have visual designed like in VS, but not require you to use it.

C++ itself have no standart way to get GUI, events (and a lot more, in fact)...

Answer (score 0):

[boost.signals documentation and tutorials will give you a good start.](http://boost.cowic.de/rc/pdf/signals.pdf)

[libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) is another alternative.